# Surface Pro 4 loses NetBIOS resolution

Tags: windows-10, netbios

In my home network are computers with a variety of OS generations, ranging from Windows XP (virtual), 7, 10. My latest computer, a Surface Pro 4 is typically able to access the virtual Windows XP system via NetBIOS name (over IPv4 since Windows XP does not have IPv6).

However after some time, under unknown conditions, this Surface Pro 4 will lose the ability to resolve the Windows XP NetBIOS name. It can still readily resolve my other Windows 10 hostname but I notice its means of contact via ping is IPv6. I do not truly know if it has something to do with me regularly sleeping the computer since after all it's a tablet and I frequently flip the keyboard cover when not in use.

- Renewing the network adapter's DHCP leases do not work.
- Disabling and re-enabling the adapter devices do not work.
- Clearing nbtstat cache does not work, since it appears to lose the ability to resolve so there's nothing to cache in the first place.
- Setting the network adapter's NetBIOS setting to be hard enabled over TCP/IP does not help.

This is not a problem with the Windows XP system because the only way to get it working again now is to *restart* the Surface Pro 4. Thereafter NetBIOS resolution resumes for a duration of time until the next break down.

What are some conditions in a Windows 10 system that can lead its network adapters to fail NetBIOS resolution over IPv4?

UPDATE

I have currently worked around the problem by hardcoding the remote Windows XP NetBIOS name into the LMHOSTS file. However, this does not explain at all why NetBIOS name resolution "goes to sleep" and how I can possibly awake it without an entire system restart.